# What is the constructor of the window object？

Tags: javascript

All data in js can be regarded as objects, and objects are instantiated by their constructors through the new keyword, such as array, Date, String, Number, Object, then what is the constructor of the top-level object Window?

Comment: What is the question about (meaning the question already contains the answer)? Constructor of `window` object is `Window`, try in browser console `console.log(window.constructor)` or `console.log(Window)` or `console.log(window.constructor===Window)`. And then `new Window()` :-)

Comment: "*objects are instantiated by their constructors through the new keyword*" - no. Objects can also be instantiated as function/regex/array/object literals, be returned from normal functions (e.g. `Object.create`), or be built natively into the environment by the engine.

Comment: new Window() will be show VM587:1 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor..